# ZMQ C++ server with NodeJS client

Tags: c++, node.js, server, client, zeromq

I have a C++ server with ZeroMQ and I want to add a NodeJS client using ZMQ module.

So I have a C++ server (Dispatcher that bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:5555)
 and a NodeJS Client that looks like :

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
request = zmq.socket('req');

request.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

request.send('a message sent from nodejs client');

request.on('mesage', function(msg){
    console.log('Response: ', + msg);
});
```

When I start the client, the dispatcher crash when it try to send a message to the client as the haven't the same structure.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I can't receive a message from the server ! is it true to use on('message') event ? may be the zmq c++ server doesn't support this event ?

Comment: You seem to be confusing things here - your server, written in C++, crashes when you attempt to send to your client, written in node.js - this has nothing to do with your node.js code in the client, to have any hope of helping we'll need to see the server code. What happens if you try running your server without connecting your node.js client? Or a client written in C++? Are you sure both client and server are using the same version of zmq? I'd assume so since you're on the same machine, but worth checking.

Comment: in fact, the problem is that the server accept a vector message while the nodejs client is sending a json message !